# Dojo Build with NodeJS - Cannot Generate Layers

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, dojo

I am having trouble building a layer for my web app. I have Node installed and I can use the packages directive to compress all my files but I cannot get a layer to build despite several days of trying every possible path and directive combination I can think of.

Here is a profile I thought should work:

```
var profile = {
    // point basePath to ~/dev
    basePath: "/Users/ferg/Dropbox/webdev/x-wing_squadron_builder/www/js/",

    // point releaseDir to ~/dev/myapp-deploy
    releaseDir: "./",

    action:"release",
    optimize:"shrinksafe",
    stripConsole: "normal",
    async: 1,

    layers: {   
        "squad_builder_deploy/squad_builder_all": {
            include: [
                "squad_builder/SquadList.js",
                "squad_builder/SquadPane.js" // there are actually many more files, this is just for testing...
            ]
        }
    },

    resourceTags: {
         amd: function(filename, mid) {
             return /\.js$/.test(filename);
         }
     }
}
```

My directory structure is:

```
www
    - js
        - dojo_toolkit
            - dojo
            - dijit
            - dojox
        - squad_builder (my app)
        - squad_builder_deploy (where I want to generate my layer)
```

Running this in the terminal:

```
buildscripts ferg$ ./build.sh load=build profile=../../../squad_builder/squad_builder  -r
```

Gives me:

```
processing profile resource /Users/ferg/Dropbox/webdev/x-wing_squadron_builder/www/js/squad_builder/squad_builder.profile.js
discovering resources...
starting reading resources...
starting processing raw resource content...
starting tokenizing resource...
starting processing resource tokens...
starting parsing resource...
starting processing resource AST...
starting executing global optimizations...
starting writing resources...
error(303) Missing include module for layer. missing: squad_builder/SquadList.js; layer: squad_builder_deploy/squad_builder_all
error(303) Missing include module for layer. missing: squad_builder/SquadPane.js; layer: squad_builder_deploy/squad_builder_all
starting cleaning up...
waiting for the optimizer runner to finish...
starting reporting...
Report written to /Users/ferg/Dropbox/webdev/x-wing_squadron_builder/www/js/build-report.txt
Process finished normally.
    errors: 2
    warnings: 0
    build time: 1.734 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Module IDs are not file names. You should not have extensions on SquadList or SquadPane. You also should not be generating layers that aren’t files that already exist within your application. A layer is just an existing module file that contains many additional modules for efficiency.

Comment: I have tried both removing the file extensions and using squad_builder/SquadPane as the layer name. Neither work. Any other ideas?

Comment: The squad_builder package also needs to be registered in the build system. `packages: [ { name: 'squad_builder', location: 'squad_builder' } ]`. Other different errors may appear after that point as well.